# How to concatenate string results from multiple MongoDB records into a single result in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assuming the following records:

```
{ text: "foo"},
{ text: "bar"}
```

How can I get a result such as:

```
results: "foo bar"
```

The closest I am getting to it is to use `$addToSet` but this just creates an array with the results instead of a single string which is what I really want.

```
results: [ "foo", "bar" ]
```

Using Mongo 3.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to get an array from all the documents and then [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) with [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html) to get one string:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            text: { $push: "$text" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            text: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$text",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                        $cond: [ { "$eq": [ "$$value", "" ] }, "$$this", { $concat: [ "$$value", " ", "$$this" ] } ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

After `$group` you will get single document which contains an array of all `text` values. Then `$reduce` "scans" the array and concatenates the state (`$$value`) with currently processed item. For the first item state will be an empty string so I'm using `$cond` to avoid having whitespace on the beginning.

Comment: It works! Would you mind explaining the solution? How does it work?

Comment: @smorhaim sure, modified my answer, let me know  if that's more clear for you now