# MongoDB array as string

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion

I have a collection of docs that has a couple arrays as items,
I want to export them into a CSV, but the array obviously comes back as something like
"items" : ["one","two",'three"]
and the spreadsheet sees these as separate one, two, three

Is there a way to convert and array like

```
["one","two",'three"]
```

to a string like this

```
"one,two,three"
```

I would prefer to do this in the aggregation query, however If I need to dump to a temp collection and convert the collection - I am ok with that.

any help appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838681/how-to-concatenate-string-results-from-multiple-mongodb-records-into-a-single-re/55838743#55838743 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/).
This applies an expression to each element in an array and combines them into a single value.

**Test data:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "key": {
        "$rtrim": {
          "input": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$key",
              "initialValue": "",
              "in": {
                "$concat": [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this",
                  ","
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "chars": ","
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": "one,two,three"
  }
]
```

The [$rtrim](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rtrim/) was used to eliminate the last `,` remaining. Without this, the result would be `"one,two,three,"`

You can test it yourself here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zNGlOw5LjeP