# How to convert array to string in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have below schema

```
{
 id: 123,
 values:[
   {valueId: "12444", name: "asd"},
   {valueId: "555", name: "www"},
 ]
}
```

i want to convert it into (combine `name` into single string)

```
{
 id: 123,
 values: "asdwww"
}
```

i have tried below aggregate which puts all name value in an array

```
$project: {
      attributes: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$attributes",
          "as": "attr",
          "in": {
            "id": "$$attr.id",
            "values": "$$attr.values.name"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

which makes it into

```
{
 id: 123,
 values:[
     "asd",
     "www"
   ]
}
```

i want to have values as single string value as `"asd,www"` or `"asdwww"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) instead of `$map`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            values: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$values",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: { $concat: [ "$$value", "$$this.name" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eGQqkKWu9_k)

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838681/how-to-concatenate-string-results-from-multiple-mongodb-records-into-a-single-re/55838743#55838743) which shows how to handle delimiters